# How to connect to Spring based Websockets via Java based client (Java class or Unit Test)?

Tags: java, spring, junit, websocket, spring-websocket

Am new to WebSockets...

Am learning how to implement Spring based WebSockets by following the coding tutorial:

```
http://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring
```

My maven pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

WebSocket Controller:

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    @MessageMapping("/messages")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public OutputMessage send(final Message message) throws Exception {
        final String time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
        return new OutputMessage(message.getFrom(), message.getText(), time);
    }
}
```

Output Message:

```
public class OutputMessage {

    private String from;
    private String text;
    private String time;

    // Constructor
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Message (incoming):

```
public class Message {

    private String from;
    private String text;

    // Constructor
    // Getters and Setters
}
```

When I deploy the war file into my Tomcat 7 container and open up a browser and point it to:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/messages
```

Received the following response in the Web Browser:

```
Can "Upgrade" only to "WebSocket".
```

The author of the tutorial used JavaScript as the client for accessing this Web Socket...

Question(s):

1. How can I access this web socket (publish a message and see the outcoming message in the response) via Java code (instead of JavaScript)?
2. Is there a Java library (preferably one that works with Spring) that will let me do this (sorry a lot of examples on the Internet are JavaScript web socket clients)?
3. Is there a way to access this call via a JUnit Test?
4. Should I be using a different port under than 8080 for WebSockets? If so, how can I configure this?

Comment: Can you post your code that deals directly with sending / receiving messages? Are you using any special libraries or just pure Java right now?

Comment: Haven't tried in pure Java cuz there's no good documentation - hence the reason for this post. Specifically asked for Java based libraries since I didn't know the answer.

Comment: Java has built in support for web sockets: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/websocket.htm

Comment: Are you trying to make a client or a server?

Comment: Trying to make a sample client to connect to this websocket... Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Check this out then - https://dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client

Comment: The author is using a library other than Spring's Websocket library... Spring Websocket library is based on the Stomp.

Comment: Did you have success? I have done something like this... https://github.com/jesjobom/websocket-client-spring-example